# Cross table with filtered obs on R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, crosstab, summarytools

I'd like to make a crosstable where x is the number of distinct obs of a variable and y is an other variable. With dplyr I can get the information I need with the code below but it obviously does not create a table. What I would like is the number of distinct obs of *CODE_UAI.x*  for *secteur*. Below is an example of the data set.

| CODE_UAI.x | secteur |
| --- | --- |
| 0271564D | 1 |
| 0942344M | 2 |
| 0271564D | 3 |
| 0332894S | 3 |
| 0033082C | 2 |
| 00381324H | 1 |
| 0271564D | 3 |
| 0033082C | 2 |

- Code for input `dataframe`

```r
df1 <- data.frame("CODE_UAI.x" = c("0271564D", "0942344M", "0271564D", "0332894S",
                                   "0033082C", "00381324H", "0271564D", "0033082C"),
                  secteur = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2))
```

```
Ech_final_nom_BSA %>%
  filter(secteur == 3) %>%
  summarise(n=n_distinct(CODE_UAI.x))
```

I've also tried doing this with the package summarytools with no results.

The results I'm expecting is something like this:

| Secteur | # distinct UAI |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

I hope this makes sense. Feel free to ask further information if needed.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: How is the last value 3 ? Are you looking for `df %>% group_by(secteur) %>% summarise(distinct = n_distinct(CODE_UAI.x))`

Comment: You're right it should be 2 and yes this totally works!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `filter`, you can instead do `group_by` for each `secteur` and count unique values using `n_distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(secteur) %>% summarise(n=n_distinct(CODE_UAI.x))

#  secteur     n
#    <dbl> <int>
#1       1     2
#2       2     2
#3       3     2
```

Or in base R -

```
aggregate(CODE_UAI.x~ secteur, df1, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```